# XSLT 1.0: Can I re-use 'test' logic in mulitple if tests?

Tags: xslt

I am using XSLT 1.0 to generate an EXCEL (2003 format) XML file output.
I am having to scan the input document twice (once for headers, once for data); I don't want to process all input elements in the XML, so I have an 'xsl:if' construction like this:

```
<xsl:if test="name(.) != 'ID' and name(.) != 'LINE' and name(.) != 'VERSION' and name(.) !='EXTRA'">
        <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="{$excelType}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></ss:Data></ss:Cell>
</xsl:if>
```

Since I need to skip the same inputs when I am processing header and data - can I re-use the logic of the if ? Currently I have two identical 'if' statements that I have to keep in sync.

That is: can I hold the conditional logic of the 'test' attribute in a string and then apply this twice ? (or something else?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to answer without context. In general, to reuse something, you put it in a *variable*, for example:

```
<xsl:variable name="my-nodes" select="some-node[name()!='ID' and name()!='LINE' and name()!='VERSION' and name()!='EXTRA']" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="$my-nodes" mode="header"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="$my-nodes"/>
```

Here, you would have two templates matching `some-node`, one of them with a `mode` attribute set to `"header"`.

Or:

```
<xsl:variable name="my-nodes" select="some-node[name()!='ID' and name()!='LINE' and name()!='VERSION' and name()!='EXTRA']" />
<xsl:for-each select="$my-nodes">
    <!-- header-->
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="$my-nodes">
    <!-- data-->
</xsl:for-each>
```